# Calculating the number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

> Let A be a set with *n* elements. For which *n* do (exactly) subsets $B_1,
>  \cdots, B_{2^{n-1}} \subseteq A$ exist, so $B_i \neq B_j, B_i \cap B_j
>  \neq \emptyset$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq 2^{n-1}$ and
>    $\bigcap_{i=1}^{2^{n-1}} B_i = \emptyset$.

It is clear that such subsets cannot be created for $n \leq 2$.

Do you have any idea how this can be calculated?

I tried to find such subsets, but always found more subsets than $2^{n-1}$, so there should be some misunderstanding or mistake in my thoughts:

Consider $n=3, A = \{1,2,3\}$. Subsets where no element is contained in all subsets could be all subsets $\subsetneq A$ $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,1\}\}$. There is no element which is present in all of theses subsets, but for each item another one can be found, so that the intersection of both isn't empty.

Where is my mistake? How can the real solution be calculated?

Comment: What does $B_i \cap B_j >\ne \emptyset$ mean?

Comment: @vonbrand that was inserted by the formatting function of SE, sorry for that. I just removed it.

Comment: What are the sets $A_i$?

Comment: @ellya It was a typing error, sorry for that

Comment: You can't have the intersections being empty and non empty

Comment: @ellya Consider $X$ = {{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}}. $\forall 1 \leq i,j \leq 3, i \neq j: X_i \cap X_j \neq \emptyset. \bigcap_{i=1}^3 X_i = \emptyset$. For each tuple of items there is at least one common element in the subsets. But the overall intersection is empty as there is no element in all of the subsets. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad

Comment: So what you really want is to know the *maximum* number $k$ for which there are $k$ pairwise distinct, pairwise non-disjoint subsets of $A = \{1, \dots, n\}$ with (overall) empty intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Added: In the first version of this answer, I forgot to show that $\bigcap \mathcal{B}=\emptyset$. Thanks to muffel for following up.*

---

This is possible for all $n>2$.

Suppose $n>1$ is odd. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{B\subseteq A:|B|>\frac{1}{2}|A| \}$. The collection $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the requirements of the problem.

No two sets in $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint, because if they were, their union would contain more than $n$ elements.

Furthermore, $$|\mathcal{B}|=\sum\limits_{k=\frac{n+1}{2}}^n {n\choose k}=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{n+1}{2}}^n 2{n\choose k}=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{n+1}{2}}^n \left({n\choose k}+{n\choose n-k}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}=2^{n-1}.$$

Finally, $\bigcap \mathcal{B}=\emptyset$. This will hold if for every $a\in A$, $\mathcal{B}$ contains at least one subset of $A$ that doesn’t contain $a$, and it does. For each $a\in A$, $A-\{a\}\in \mathcal{B}$, because $| A-\{a\}|>\frac{1}{2}|A|$ (because $n-1>\frac{n}{2}$ when $n>2$).

Suppose n>2 is even. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{B\subseteq A:|B|>\frac{1}{2}|A| \}\cup \{B\subseteq A:1\in B \}$. Again $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies the requirements. No two sets in $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint, because if they were, either their union would contain more than $n$ elements (if either one has size $>\frac{1}{2}|A|$), or their intersection would contain $1$ (if both have size $\frac{1}{2}|A|$).

In addition,

$\begin{align}
|\mathcal{B}|&=\sum\limits_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n {n\choose k}+{n-1\choose{\frac{n}{2}-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \left({n\choose k}+{n\choose k}\right)+2{n-1\choose{\frac{n}{2}-1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \left({n\choose k}+{n\choose n-k}\right)+{n-1\choose{\frac{n}{2}-1}}+{n-1\choose{n-1-(\frac{n}{2}-1)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{n}{2}+1}^n \left({n\choose k}+{n\choose n-k}\right)+\left({n-1\choose{\frac{n}{2}-1}}+{n-1\choose{\frac{n}{2}}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}-{n\choose{n/2}}\right)+{n\choose{n/2}}
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}\\
&=2^{n-1}
\end{align}$

Finally, $\bigcap \mathcal{B}=\emptyset$. The argument used for odd $n$ applies without modification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain to me why $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies both requirements? I understand why no two subsets are disjoint. But why is $\bigcap_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B = \emptyset$?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to show in my answer that the intersection is empty. Fortunately, it’s true, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the addition, but I still don't get it: You say $\forall a \in A: A \setminus \{a\} \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow\exists B \in \mathcal{B}: a \not\in B$. Why does this apply?

Comment: To show $\cap\mathcal{B}$ is empty, we need to show that $a_1\notin\cap\mathcal{B}$,$a_2\notin\cap\mathcal{B}$, etc. What does it mean for $a$ to be in the intersection? $a\in\cap\mathcal{B}$ if and only if $a$ is in every one of the sets in $\mathcal{B}$. Therefore, to show that the intersection *fails* to contain $a$, we need to find just one set in $\mathcal{B}$ that fails to contain $a$. That's it. If we can show that for each $a\in A$, there is at least one set in $\mathcal{B}$ that fails to contain $a$, we have excluded every element of $A$ from possibly being in $\cap\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Or maybe more clearly. If you don't believe $\bigcap\mathcal{B}$ is empty, tell me what element you think it might contain. (I’ll pretend you say “$a$”.) My response: Sorry, $a$ is definitely not in $\bigcap\mathcal{B}$, because one of the sets being intersected is $A-\{a\}$, and $a$ can’t be in $(A-\{a\})\cap X$ for any set $X$ at all.

Comment: Ah, I got it now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For $n=3$ you need $2^{n-1}=4$ subsets with the property desired, and an example would be:

$\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\}$

And the problem you are having, i.e. always finding more than $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $A$, is caused by the fact that the set of all sets (the power set), **always** contains $2^n$ sets.

Comment: @ella my problem is that I (seem to) find more than $2^{n-1}$ subsets **that comply** with the condition, instead of exactly $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: oh, that wasn't in your question

Comment: sorry, I thought that this was clear. I added 'exactly' to the question

Comment: Oh I see, right I get it now

Comment: The example you posted doesn't hold all the conditions, as $\{1\}\cap\{2\}=\emptyset$

Comment: and if you try to put in any other singletons into my example, it doesn't work, so I think my example is the solution.